# How can I determine why my JSON object fails?

Tags: json, ajax, vbscript

In the following code, I am trying to get the data using ajax but it fails and alerts the error message in the ajax call.

I need the data in the object to populate a form. It just alerts "Ooop there is something wrong" in the error of the ajax call.

Please find below my ajax call. As I said previously it alert the error message and since it is not successful, nothing to show in the developer tool on my browser for console.log()

````
dim rstRev, strRevSQL
dim intReviewStatus
dim intReviewID

intReviewID = sqlsafe2(request("review_id"),2)


Set rstRev = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strRevSQL = "exec ppsp_reviewDetails '" & intReviewID & "'"

rstRev.open strRevSQL, db,adOpenForwardOnly,adLockReadOnly

if not rstRev.EOF then

    intValueScore   = cint(rstRev("value_score"))
    intQualityScore = cint(rstRev("quality_score"))
    intReview_ID    = intReviewID
    reviewID        = rstRev("review_id")
    reviewDate      = rstRev("review_date")
    reviewEmail     =rstRev("email")
    pf_id           = rstRev("pf_id")
    product         = rstRev("product_name")
    reviewTitle     =rstRev("review_title")
    linkText        = rstRev("link_text")
    TT              = cint(rstRev("t_and_t"))
    reviewStatus    = cint(rstRev("active"))
    reviewText      = rstRev("review_text")
    ppResponse      = rstRev("pp_response")

    strJSON =   "{"                                                         & _
                        """success"": true,"                                & _
                        """intValueScore"":""" & intValueScore & ""","      & _
                        """intQualityScore"":""" & intQualityScore & ""","  & _
                        """intReview_ID"":""" & intReview_ID & ""","        & _
                        """reviewID"":""" & reviewID & ""","                & _
                        """reviewDate"":""" & reviewDate & ""","            & _
                        """reviewEmail"":""" & reviewEmail & ""","          & _
                        """pf_id"":""" & pf_id & ""","                      & _ 
                        """product"":""" & product & ""","                  & _
                        """reviewTitle"":""" & reviewTitle & ""","          & _
                        """linkText"":""" & linkText & ""","                & _
                        """TT   "":""" & TT  & ""","                        & _
                        """reviewStatus"":""" & reviewStatus & ""","        & _
                        """reviewText"":""" & reviewText & ""","            & _
                        """ppResponse"":""" & ppResponse & """"             & _


                    "}"



%>


<%

end if

rstRev.Close
set rstRev = nothing
Response.Write(strJSON) 
%>```



```$('tbody tr td a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var x =$(this).prop("href")

        var y = x.indexOf("=")+1
        revID = x.substring(y)
        //alert (x)
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            async: true,
            url:"/web_utils/ppgf_utils/ajax/xt-review_details05122019.asp",
            data:{
                review_id:revID
            },
            success:function(data){
                window.scrollTo(0, 0)
                if(data.success ==true){

                    console.log(data.success)
                }


            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Ooop Something is wrong")
            }

        });```
````

Comment: Try to put this part to detail the error that throws: `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
}`

Comment: @Julián, bunch of html like this:
menuH ul a:hover
{
    color: orange; /*colour of drop down menue items highlighted*/
}

.menuH li:hover ul, .menuH li.onhover ul
{
    left: -1px;/*Use this property to change offset of the dropdown*/
    top: auto;
}

.menuH li:hover .dropToLeft, .menuH li.onhover .dropToLeft
{
    left: auto;
    right: -1px;
    top: auto;
}
.menuH ul ul
{
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.menuH li:hover ul ul, .menuH li:hover ul ul ul, .menuH li:hover ul ul ul ul,
.menuH li.onhover ul ul, .menuH li.onhover ul ul ul, .menuH li.onhover ul ul u

Comment: @Julián, I have an included file on the page that was the reason for this error. Your response helped me to realize my problem. Thank you a billion times

Comment: No problem bro :)